# TailwindCSS Justify Content not working in CSS Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

In Tailwind CSS, the **justify content** is not working. But when I change the code from `grid-cols-3` to *Vanilla CSS* by adding a class and remove the tailwind `grid-cols-3` utility class, let's say the new `div` class name is `container`, add the following code would actually work, which makes me so confusing:

```css
.container {
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}
```

I've attached the tailwind file below:

```js
<div class="grid h-[500px] w-[500px] grid-cols-3 justify-end bg-slate-100">
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-red-200">1</div>
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-orange-200">2</div>
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-yellow-200">3</div>
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-green-200">4</div>
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-blue-200">5</div>
  <div class="h-[50px] w-[50px] bg-indigo-200">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: may i know what you want to achieve and where you are feeling difficulty

Comment: Not a CSS mage, but I think this has to do that tailwind's `grid-cols-3` results in `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));`, where the latter part instructs the grid cols to take up all available space. So there won't be any spare space for `justify-content` (via TW's `justify-something`) to distribute. This is a TW-specific thing.

Answer (score 3):

`justify-end` applies to the container (which has 3 equally sized columns that fits the whole width so it does not make sense here).

this is what you need:
`justify-items-end`, which applies inside the columns.